# Can I set the "Difference push receive setting in firebase?"

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am now trying to make a mobile app push notification service on Firebase. But the function description is not quite specific as I expected.

I want to know these functions are available on Firebase. If not, It would be pleasure If you tell me other tool.

1. User can select the push message types they want to receive.(Ex. Receive sale information push, Do not receive game event push)
2. Instantly send auto push messages when user triggered certain condition.(Ex. Send appreciate push message when user closed their first app-open)

Thank you

Comment: you can manage this types of condition from back-end . if `receivesale`  is on then send push to user , otherwise don't

Answer (score 0):

Can not tell in much description here:

**1. User can select the push message types they want to receive.(Ex.
    Receive sale information push, Do not receive game event push)**

You can use FCM's channeling feature,

- You can set different channels.
- Show the list of channels to user.
- User can subscribe to the required channel.
- User will receive the specific channel notification only.

Please refer : [Notification Channel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels)

**2. Instantly send auto push messages when user triggered certain condition.(Ex. Send appreciate push message when user closed their first app-open)**
You have manage this thing in your front end and backend logic.

Like on app close send request to the backend (can use  onDestroy method )server and then the backend server will send notification.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**For Feature 1:**

You can achieve this without even doing anything. Just send all notifications to everyone. However, use different [Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels). Users, can then choose to turn on/off certain notification channels using the Android system features (in relatively newer versions of android).

Another way could be to send these notifications to different [FCM Topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). Give the users a settings pages, where there can select what kinds of notifications they would like to receive. In response to their selections, subscribe or unsubscribe them to the respective FCM Topic.

**For Feature 2:**

There could be several hundred ways of doing this. Can provide better advice if you could provide more information about your requirement.

If you talk about your example requirement

> (Send appreciate push message when user closed their first app-open)

You can do it without any server, or push messaging scheme. Just keep track of the first_open event inside the app using [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). Once you detect a first_open event, just compose a notification inside of the app locally, and show it whenever you like.